Using Picklist with for:each lightning-input
I have a requirement to display records that can be edited.  These records will get saved but will also be used to created some different objects.
I am using the below code which works.  My first question is, how do I display the status field as a picklist field?  Second question, how do I update the record once a field is changed?  THank you!!
template for:each={oppProds} for:item="oppProd" for:index="index">
            <tr key={oppProd.Id}>
                <td><lightning-input label="Name" value={oppProd.Name} data-field="Name" disabled="true" class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input></td> 
                 <td> <lightning-input label="Status" value={oppProd.Status__c} data-field="Status" onchange={handleStatusChange} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input></td>
                 <td><lightning-input label="Estimated Contracts" value={oppProd.Estimated_Conctracts__c} data-field="contracts" onchange={handleChange} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input> </td>
                 <td><lightning-input label="Estimated Members" value={oppProd.Estimated_Members__c} data-field="members" onchange={handleChange} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input> </td>
             
             </tr>
 
        </template>


You can use the lightning-combobox component for the picklist and handle the changes in your JS controller.
In HTML replace the lightning-input for the Status field with lightning-combobox.
<template for:each={oppProds} for:item="oppProd" for:index="index">
    <tr key={oppProd.Id}>
        <td>
            <lightning-input label="Name" value={oppProd.Name} data-field="Name" disabled="true" class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
        </td>
        <td>
            <lightning-combobox label="Status" value={oppProd.Status__c} data-field="Status" options={statusOptions} onchange={handleStatusChange} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-combobox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <lightning-input label="Estimated Contracts" value={oppProd.Estimated_Conctracts__c} data-field="contracts" onchange={handleChange} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
        </td>
        <td>
            <lightning-input label="Estimated Members" value={oppProd.Estimated_Members__c} data-field="members" onchange={handleChange} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>

In the JS controller, define the options for the picklist and handle the changes. You can define the option as static or get it dynamically using the wire method. Refer to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-wire-adapters-picklist-values.html
JS controller looks like this:
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import OPP_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/ObjectName'; //replace object name with your org object name.
import STATUS_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/ObjectName.Status__c"; //replace object name with your org object name.

export default class YourComponentName extends LightningElement {
    @track oppProds = []; 
    @track statusOptions = [];

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPP_OBJECT })
    oppMetadata;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: "$oppMetadata.data.defaultRecordTypeId", fieldApiName: STATUS_FIELD })
    picklistResults({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
          this.statusOptions = data.values;
        } else if (error) {
            this.statusOptions = undefined;
          console.error(error);
        }
    }

    handleStatusChange(event) {
        const field = event.target.dataset.field;
        const value = event.detail.value;
        const index = event.target.dataset.index;
        this.oppProds[index][field] = value;
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const field = event.target.dataset.field;
        const value = event.detail.value;
        const index = event.target.dataset.index;
        this.oppProds[index][field] = value;
    }

}

Note: update the js controller accourding to your component controller. I have just added the picklist value show as combobox logic.

Thank you! For some reason, the index is null in the handleStatusChange method.
